# Rails: Post JSON to API Using Rails and HTTParty Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, httparty

I am pretty new to API in Rails, although I have gotten some assistance already about how to structure my HTTParty Post Request, but the payload (data) that I am sending does not impact on the database of my API

**All I want is to create a record on the database of the API through a POST request from my application.**

That is to create a record on both databases (my database and the on the database of the API through a POST request from my application) whenever I create a book.

For the app that will consume the API I am using the HTTParty gem, but the request only runs on the without impacting the database of the API

**Here is my HTTParty Post Request Code**

```
@result = HTTParty.post(' https://www.pingme.com/wp-json/wplms/v1/user/register',
    :body => {
                :books => {  
                  :name => '#{name}',
                  :author => '#{author}',
                  :description => '#{description}',
                  :category_id => '#{category_id}',
                  :sub_category_id => '#{sub_category_id}'}.to_json, 
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx' })
```

But this does not impact on the database of the API, rather it only impacts on the database of my Rails Application

**Here is the log code for the execution**

```
Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-27 11:51:18 +0100
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxx", "book"=>{"name"=>"veb", "author"=>"vebturejjd", "description"=>"aisiosoijjdkdp", "category_id"=>"text books", "sub_category_id"=>"children"}, "commit"=>"Create Book"}
   (0.1ms)    begin transaction

↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:32
      Book Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("name", "author", "description", "category_id", "sub_category_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "client_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "vebturejjd"], ["author", "vebturejjd"], ["description", "aisiosoijjdkdp"], ["category_id", "text books"], ["sub_category_id", "children"], ["created_at", "2019-03-27 10:51:18.239045"], ["updated_at", "2019-03-27 10:51:18.239045"]]
      ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:32
       (77.8ms)  commit transaction
```

I cannot find any log for @result in my terminal, still wondering if it was skipped or didn't run at run, or there is a better way to do it.

Please I need some help on how to parse in ruby to be posted to the database of the API.

**Here is my Books Controller for creating books**

```
require 'httparty'

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty

  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: %i[show index]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    @result = HTTParty.post(' https://www.pingme.com/wp-json/wplms/v1/user/register',
    :body => {
                :books => {  
                  :name => '#{name}',
                  :author => '#{author}',
                  :description => '#{description}',
                  :category_id => '#{category_id}',
                  :sub_category_id => '#{sub_category_id}'}.to_json, 
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx' })

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :description, :category_id, :sub_category_id)
    end
end
```

**Please any form of assistance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Could you log what `@result` is? Also do you have any way to see the logs of the API your are posting to in order to see if the call is received on that end?

Comment: If you inspect the reponse status and body of your `@result` variable you might have more insight about what's happening.

Comment: I don't understand how `@result` can be showing you that. Those variables need to be in double quotes, not single to interpolate correctly and even then "#{name}" should be undefined. "#{@book.name}" should have a value though. Also, you never pass the authenticity token and the key is wrong "book" vs "books".

Comment: I have updated the question to explicitly show the log for **@result**

I don't have access at the moment to see the logs of the API that I am posting to. However, I get a successful response whenever I test the API using Postman.

I need your assistance please, I am stuck here.

Thank you.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone, thank you for pointing out that, I just realized that the whole log code is just for **book create action**.

I am so sorry for that misconception, I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails.

I have updated the question. Do you know any better way to go about this, because i cant find any log for **result**.

Thank you.

Comment: @PromisePreston Whew, I was worried that the world didn't make sense anymore :) I posted a possible solution, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Following contributions from @vincent-rolea and @oneWorkingHeadphone, I found a working solution to the issue.

**Here is the corrected HTTParty Post Request that worked for me.**

```
@results = HTTParty.post(' https://www.pingme.com/wp-json/wplms/v1/user/register',
      :body => {    
                :name => "#{@book.name}",
                :author => "#{@book.author}",
                :description => "#{@book.description}",
                :category_id => "#{@book.category_id}",
                :sub_category_id => "#{@book.sub_category_id}"}.to_json, 
      :headers => { 
                   'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                   'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx'
      }
)
```

**Ensure to do the following to make to work**

1. Install and confgure the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) in your application
2. Include and require the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) in the controller where you want the request to be performed
3. Pass the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) post request to an instance variable of in that controller

**Here is the inplementation of the HTTParty Post Request in my controller**

```
require 'httparty'

class BooksController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty

  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: %i[show index]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.search(params[:keywords]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    @results = HTTParty.post(' https://www.pingme.com/wp-json/wplms/v1/user/register',
          :body => {    
                    :name => "#{@book.name}",
                    :author => "#{@book.author}",
                    :description => "#{@book.description}",
                    :category_id => "#{@book.category_id}",
                    :sub_category_id => "#{@book.sub_category_id}"}.to_json, 
          :headers => { 
                       'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                       'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx'
          }
    )
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :description, :category_id, :sub_category_id)
    end
end
```

That's all

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: What is different about this code from what you posted in the question?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone, the difference is the way I called the HTTParty post request body key values:

**:name => "#{@book.name}"**  and not **:name => '#{name}'**

Which is what I got to implement from your contibution.

However, I assigned my HTTParty Post Request to an instance variable in the create action of the books controller, while you defined a new action for the HTTParty Post Request, which didn't work for me when I tried it.

Thank you so much for your assistance, I wouldn't have been able to pull this through without your help. I am very grateful.

Comment: Your instance variable assignment has the side effect of calling the post request. Since the instance variable isn't used after this it isn't necessary. I would still suggest that you wrap it in a method as your intention is more clear when someone comes back to this code.

Answer (score 0):

`@result` is never called in your controller because the redirect happens before the execution gets there.

I would wrap the HTTP call in a method rather than assign it to an instance variable since it is transacting things, not assigning them then bring it inside you `format.html {}` block. Something like this:

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html {
        post_to_api 
        redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' 
      }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def post_to_api
  HTTParty.post(' https://www.pingme.com/wp-json/wplms/v1/user/register',
    :body => {
              :books => {  
                :name => "#{@book.name}",
                :author => "#{@book.author}",
                :description => "#{@book.description}",
                :category_id => "#{@book.category_id}",
                :sub_category_id => "#{@book.sub_category_id}"}.to_json, 
    :headers => { 
              'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
              'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much **@oneWorkingHeadphone.**

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I guess it's because there is no place in my form for creating books that the **post_to_api** action is called.

Maybe you could specify a way of calling this action on the **create books form**

However, your answer helped me to modify my code to make it work.

I will post my answer, so that you will see the solution that worked for me